# Need to create a custom report builder

Tags: report

I need to provide a facility on my website where the user can create his own reports. So, he will be shown various fields and using drag drop options he should be able to decide what fields he wants in his report. He should also be able to add filters and then create his own reports. What is the best way to do this?

My frontend is in PHP - Laravel framework and SQL is the backend.

Comment: good start. now, we need some code for us to help you with. see -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also,all my tables are interrelated. So,one thought was to create one large view of all tables and columns and display the field alaises to the user. Depending on the fields selected by user,data can be fetched from the views. But I am not sure if this is recommended.